# apiclient.discovery.build POST request body

Tags: python, google-app-engine, http-post, google-api-client

I am using python for both my server Google App Engine API code and my client.  I have plenty of client-server GET requests working already, now it's time for a POST request and I'm stuck.  My relevant client code:

```
service = build("myAPI", "v1", http=http, discoveryServiceUrl=DISCOVERY_URL)
service.updateUser(websafeKey=websafeKey).execute()
```

I can't figure out how to build the body of the POST request.  After that I will be stuck trying to figure out how to tell `service` about it so that it can send the request to my updateUser API.

The POST request body will need to contain some strings and several lists, and later possibly a python Date object.

My `updateUser` API works fine in the API Explorer - I can successfully `updateUser` all day long:

```
USER_POST_REQUEST = endpoints.ResourceContainer(
UserForm, websafeKey=messages.StringField(1),)
@endpoints.method(USER_POST_REQUEST, UserForm,
        path='useradmin/{websafeKey}',
        http_method='PUT', name='updateUser')
def updateUser(self, request):
    """Update user w/provided fields & return w/updated info."""
    return self._updateUserObject(request)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out myself.  Apparently all you need to do is define a dictionary and pass it as the `body` parameter in the service method call.  Here's what I did:

```
body = {'key1': user['info1'], 'key2': user['info2']}
service = build("myAPI", "v1", http=http, discoveryServiceUrl=DISCOVERY_URL)
service.updateFan(websafeFanKey=fan['websafeKey'], body=body).execute()
```

Pretty simple, really, but it sure was difficult for me to find anything that documented this.  Hopefully someone else can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

```
body = {"messages":"XXX"}

pubsubpublisher = googleapiclient.discovery.build('pubsub', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

response = pubsubpublisher.projects().topics().publish(topic='projects/{project-number}/topics/{topic-name}',body=body).execute()
```

This works

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).